# Kendo ASP.NET MVC - Index Out of Range Databinding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm getting the following error when trying to bind a datatable to a Telerik Kendo Grid:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**

I've followed Telerik's example project, but in my code it seems to be failing on the 'Read' function of 'DataSource':

**.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Events"))**

I have ActionResult Read() is currently returning null, just because I wanted to see if it'd even make it to that function. Also, I've stepped through and the datatable is returning the correct columns and column names.

Any help is appreciated.

*Events.cshtml*

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Events";
    Layout = "~/Views/_mainLayout.cshtml";
}

<p>Events</p>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("GridStatic")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound("ID");
        columns.Bound("EntryType");
        columns.Bound("EventDate");
        columns.Bound("EventData");
        columns.Bound("Source");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()       
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Field("ID", typeof(int));
                model.Field("EntryType", typeof(DateTime));
                model.Field("EventDate", typeof(string));
                model.Field("EventData", typeof(string));
                model.Field("Source", typeof(string));
            })
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Events"))
    )
)
```

*EventsController.cs*

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Events/

    public ActionResult Events(string sName)
    {
        EventReader ereader = new EventReader(sName);
        return View(ereader.ParseIntoTable(ereader.GetListOfEvents()));
    }

    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE::**

Here is the stack trace, I'm not sure if that will help.

```
    [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than    the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: index]
     System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +72
   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value) +10451574
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.get_RequestContext() +25
   Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigatableExtensions.GenerateUrl(INavigatable navigatable, ViewContext viewContext, IUrlGenerator urlGenerator) +52
   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilder.SetUrl() +81
   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilder.Action(String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues) +66
   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilder.Action(String actionName, String controllerName) +47
   ASP._Page_Views_Events_Events_cshtml.b__3(CrudOperationBuilder read) in c:\Users\wsharp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Inviso\Inviso\Views\Events\Events.cshtml:40
   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.AjaxDataSourceBuilderBase`2.Read(Action`1 configurator) +131
   ASP._Page_Views_Events_Events_cshtml.b__2(DataSourceBuilder`1 dataSource) in c:\Users\wsharp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Inviso\Inviso\Views\Events\Events.cshtml:30
   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder`1.DataSource(Action`1 configurator) +212
   ASP._Page_Views_Events_Events_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\wsharp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Inviso\Inviso\Views\Events\Events.cshtml:16
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass1a.b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass1c.b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: If you return an empty result set, does it work???

Comment: @BrianMains - I set it to return an empty data table, but got the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it was related to my web.config. I was running into errors with every Kendo object I created. Adding the following code to the top level web.config seemed to fix everything.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: One of the possible causes of the error is that an older than 4.0 version of System.Web.Mvc can be loaded if your project is a 'legacy' project that you have added Kendo UI to.  When the data is returned from the server, the format is unrecognizable and causes the error.  By adding this in the top level web.config you force the newest version to load with your site.

Answer (score 4):

By including  section in your solution's web.config file will help you.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate that the error is occurring because the `Read` action is not returning a valid result set.

Usually the Kendo grid requires a `JsonResult` to be returned when reading in Ajax mode. If you return an empty `DataTable` correctly formatted as a json result then I suspect that would fix it.

```
  public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
  {
     return this.Json(new DataTable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
  }
```

Obviously you should substitute the `DataTable` for your real result set.

Comment: I made that change, but I still receive the error. I have a breakpoint on the entry to that function, but it's not even reaching that. Could this error result from not being able to find the action or controller?

Comment: Can you monitor the ajax request in the browser and see what response code you are getting? The http status code would tell you whether the route is not being found or whether there's an authorization issue or server error.

Comment: I'll look at that right now. Also, I've updated my post with the stack trace, I'm not sure if that will be helpful.

Comment: HTTP is returning a status 500.

Comment: Ok, well that shows that the error is happening on the initial page load, the Ajax request doesn't even get a chance to fire. The stack trace seems to point to a problem building the Read URL of the datasource, not quite sure what the exact problem is at the moment though. I've copied your example and just used a non-existing route and it works for me using the latest Kendo release.

Comment: I just grabbed the latest version and tried it again. Still no luck. It must be either my computer or the data table.

Comment: The stack trace looks like it's pointing to an issue resolving the RequestContext. I think there must be some other factor coming into play here external of the Kendo grid or your controller actions. Can you check the value of the RequestContext in your view before the grid is built using @ViewContext.RequestContext?

Comment: It's not null, is there something specific I should look for in the RequestContext?

Comment: I moved part of my code into the Telerik project and it's now generating the Grid. I'll have to track down the exact piece of code that's causing the problem. Thanks for your help.